# fulfillRandomness in Chainlink VRF?

Tags: chainlink

After executing the `requestRandomness`  function

```
function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
    return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
}
```

it returns the `requestId` by default but does it also return `randomness` to be used as an argument in the `fulfillRandomness` function?

```
function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
    randomResult = randomness;
}
```

Or do I pass in any random number as an argument for `fulfillRandomness` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your requesting transaction `requestRandomness` returns a bytes32 and it emits an event that an off-chain Chainlink node is looking for.

Once the off-chain Chainlink node reads the event, it then creates the random number and the *node* is the one that calls the `fulfillRandomness` function**, and it passes the random number that it created along with the original requestId.

Using an off-chain oracle follows the [request and receive cycle](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data). You get the random number in the second transaction.

***techncially, the node calls the `vrf coordinator` which then calls the fulfillRandomness function. But don't worry about that if it's confusing. *

Comment: So when I execute the requestRandomness function it also executes fufillRandomness asynchronously?

Comment: Exactly correct. The chainlink node will actually kick off that method later in a 2nd transaction.